# Searchview in toolbar not filling all available space

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-search, android-developer-api

I want to make it so that the search view inside my toolbar takes all the available space. As of now, it doesn't, instead, it leaves a slither of unused space right next to the back button. I want it to take up more of that space.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Here is my Menu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ticker_searchview"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/tickersearch"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Here is my Toolbar XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is the relevant java code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tickersearch_menu, menu);

        SearchView tickerSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.ticker_searchview).getActionView();

        tickerSearchView.setQueryHint("Ticker Symbol or Name");

        tickerSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        tickerSearchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        TextView tickerSearchViewTextView = tickerSearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

        tickerSearchViewTextView.setTypeface(font);

        tickerSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            final Intent toStockInfo = new Intent(Search.this, stockinfo.class);

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                toStockInfo.putExtra("STOCKTICKER", query.toUpperCase());
                startActivity(toStockInfo);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                newSearchUpdateRecyclerContent(newText.toUpperCase());

                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal That's really all the XML code I have of the SearchView. Nothing really pertains to it unless you would like me to give more of the Search.java code.

Answer (score 0):

What is your toolbar XML file?

Do this in your toolbar.xml

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```